# Standard errors of *partial* two stage least squares coefficients

Tags: econometrics, sas, instrumental-variables, generalized-moments, 2sls

Here *partial* 2SLS (I coined this term and found it descriptive) is the approach that SAS uses for 2SLS. Compared to "ordinary" 2SLS which in the first stage projects **all** explanatory variables $X$ onto the column space of the instrumental variable matrix $Z$, partial 2SLS will first allow some of the explanatory variables to be labelled as `endogenous` whereas the others are left as exogenous, and in the first stage only `endogenous` variables will be projected onto $Z$ and exogenous variables will remain unchanged. Below I'll post the details for how SAS computes the coefficients for the partial 2SLS approach, or you can just go to check SAS's [`syslin` manual](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/ets/132/syslin.pdf) (p2144-2145):

> [image]
>   [image]

The above gives an explicit formula for computing the coefficients. However, I couldn't find within the manual how to estimate the *standard errors* of the coefficients. Note that, since we're no longer using the "ordinary" 2SLS, the classical 2SLS estimator that appears in many places on the Internet or in the econometrics tutorials (e.g. Greene's book) is no longer suitable here.

Hence, what would be an appropriate estimator for $\Bbb V(\widehat\delta_{2SLS})$ under the partial 2SLS model? Or, is there any way to find out how SAS computes it in details? Thanks!

EDIT: it can be shown that, under the exogeneity assumptions that
$$\Bbb E(\epsilon\mid \mathbf x) = 0,\quad \Bbb E(\epsilon\mid \mathbf z)=0$$
the partial 2SLS estimator $\widehat\delta_{2SLS}$ is still (asymptotically) *consistent*. But it's not clear to me whether $\widehat\delta_{2SLS} - \text{vec}([\beta,\gamma])$ still asymptotically follows a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ contains the exogenous regressors, then the variables in $X$ are also part of $Z$, the set of instruments. It is then superfluous to project the variables in $X$ on $Z$, as finding the predicted values of a regression of a variable onto itself and something else always returns the variable itself as fitted values, as nothing predicts a variable as well as the variable itself - in fact, it does so without error:

Say, you want to explain height of people via gender, age and...height. The fitted value for someone who is 1m81 will always be 1m81 given that s/he is male/female, of whatever age and 1m81.

There is then also no issue about other standard errors.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is: if some of X are exogenous but I don't want them to also be instruments, then they won't be part of Z.

Comment: OK, but is that the question? I do not think that this is what SAS does.

Comment: yes SAS does allow for non-instrumental exogenous variables. This is exactly what the manual shows, and is also confirmed by my hard coded test examples (I got the same regression coefficients).

Comment: Of course it does allow for non-instrumental exogenous variables. The question is if the exogenous regressors are part of the regressors of the first stage regression. And your screenshot and the pages you link to in the manual are unclear (at least to me and as it stands) about that, as they do not show how $Z$ is defined. Let $\tilde Z$ denote the instruments that are not $X$. If $Z=(X\;\tilde Z)$ then there is no "partial 2SLS". If $Z=\tilde Z$, there is.

Comment: But of course it would be interesting to see the "hard coded test examples" - although I cannot promise I'll be able to make sense of them, as I do not use SAS.

Comment: $Z$ doesn't depend on the exog, it can be specified by the users as other variables. My hard coded example is in Python, I used that to confirm SAS uses the partial 2sls approach I described in my post. (As a tangential note, I personally dislike SAS so I was just trying as much as possible to use other softwares that can match the SAS results for my assignments, whose solutions are unfortunately given in SAS.)

Comment: I never used SAS, but generally like open source software more (and the debate about SAS' manual does nothing to change that..). Specifying the external instruments as "other variables" does not automatically imply "partial 2SLS", as (I believe Stata does it that way) labelling one or more variables as the "endogenous" ones in the structural equation allows the software to infer that the remaining regressors are to be included in the set of instruments. In that case, what is specified as "other variables" just lists the external instruments (that are not part of the structural equation).